# Visual studio regular expressions with "not"

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to do this search with regular expressions:
Find a line with "style=" and not "display"

Could someone tell me the line to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?!.*display.*).*style=.*)$
```

You should use this regex with multiline option.. I do not have visual studio, therefore I do not know whether it works with visual studio or not. It works with eclipse.

EDIT :

It seems that Visual Studio has its own regex syntax. That is why my solution did not work..
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html

Comment: @Olivier, eclipse rocks :) at least on regex .. :)

Comment: @Olivier,there are some solutions such as http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/CSharpEditorWithCompletion.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Visual Studio supports lookaheads.  If you like, you can do this from a command prompt.

```
find /v /i "display" *.cs|find /i "style="
```

`/i` means ignore case.  `/v` means to ignore lines that match.  /n includes the line numbers.